# Download a File Based From Add-On

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm building an add-on which launches an executable to enable advanced and intelligent proxy. I've been able to launch the executable perfectly but the exe is of decent size and I need a different one for each OS.

I don't want to package them all into the add-on because that would result in a unnecessarily large file size. I would like the add-on to download the correct file for the client's OS after it's installed.

I found nsIDownloader but the only method it has is init() which takes an observer and a download location. I have no idea how I would give it the web server location. It seems like a significant amount of documentation on it is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nsIDownloader` may sound like it is a good place to start, but it really is just a low-level helper API, and discouraged these days because it does synchronous I/O on the main/UI thread.

I'd instead use the relatively new, and asynchronous [`Downloads.fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Downloads.jsm#fetch%28%29) high-level helper.

E.g. the following will work in a Scratchpad. It would work in any add-on as well, if the execution environment has `console` (e.g. overlays, or [`Console.jsm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Debugging_JavaScript#Browser_Console)), or the debug `console.log` calls where removed.

```
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Task.jsm");
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Downloads.jsm");

Task.spawn(function() {
  var file = Services.dirsvc.get("TmpD", Ci.nsIFile);
  file.append("test.download");
  try {
    yield Downloads.fetch("http://example.org/", file);
    console.log(file.path);
    console.log(file.exists());
    console.log(file.fileSize);
  }
  catch (ex) {
    console.log("Download Failed", ex);
  }
});
```